# Extruding an object removes edge loops

Tags: extrude, loop

I am trying to create a road. The road object is currently conformed to a terrain object but it is flat on the z axis. I want to extrude the road on the z axis then bevel the top outside edges a bit to give the sides of the road a realistic look instead of being so sharp/boxy.

Currently, before extruding, the outside edge of the road is selectable via edge select (alt + LMB). But as soon as I extrude on the z axis. The new edge on the top of the road is no longer selectable via alt - LMB.  I have tried extruding the faces and vertices but no luck.

https://www.loom.com/share/21a88c2882a04dd48144532bec5393bd

Road with edge loop selected: [image: Road with edge loop selected]
Extruded road with attempted edge loop select: [image: Extruded road with attempt to select edge loop]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: that's normal behavior as these edges are next to non quad faces. they are selectable when on border of the shape. but once you have extruded them, they no more make an edge loop (meaning there is no more a calculatable way to select them).

Answer (score 0):

You should start with tidy quad topology in the first place. My recommendation would be to remodel the road from scratch and make it with quads to make your life easier. If you had some specific shape already that you don't want to loos, you could select the vertices on the edges of the road, invert selection with Ctrl+I and delete everything else with X->Vetrices, then make sure both sides have the same number of vertices (subdividing edges and using Space function form the Loop Tools add-on is very useful here) and bridge them. If you have tidy quad geometry, you will be able to easily select loops and rings.

Else than that, you can also make the selection unique somehow so that it can be reselected easier later. There are quite a lot of ways to so. For example you can use Shift + G to call Select Similar menu and you can see various properties of mesh elements that can be compared for selection:

[image]

So you could use sharpness, crease, freestyle mark or other properties to temporarily save your selection. You can mostly set these from Vertex(Ctrl+V), Edge(Ctrl+E) and Face(Ctrl+F) menus. You could also use vertex groups or face maps.